# Why total installed size of packages are often multiple size of the downloaded binaries?

Tags: software-installation, package-management

I decided it is about time to move into the XXI century and replace my netctl network solution with network manager;

```
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (10) {bluez-libs-5.44-1 (...) networkmanager-1.6.2-3}

Total Download Size:    4.59 MiB
Total Installed Size:  29.84 MiB
```

Installed size is about 6X the downloaded size, where does this extra 'weight' come from? I mean in general, not this example-specific? Can this even be explained in 'general' terms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic reason is compression: packages are compressed, so the download size is reduced compared to the installation size. In some cases the compression can be *very* effective.

Other factors come into play with many packaging tools:

- when upgrading packages, some distributions support downloading binary delta packages, which reduces the download size even further;
- when re-installing packages, some tools take your local cache into account — so if you’ve already downloaded a package which needs to be installed (but it’s not installed *yet*), that download size isn’t taken into account.